# condition inside numpy index bracket?

Tags: numpy

I'm looking for numpy documentation stating this following operation can be done. Could someone tell where I should refer to?

```
image = np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3))
image[image < 10] = 0
>> image

[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 0 10 11]]
```

Comment: `image < 10` returns new matrix of `bool` type, indicating whether the element is less than 10, or not. Indexing operator `[]` then looks if the index is a matrix (and of the same shape), and if it is, returns a corresponding subset of the matrix. So you should be looking for indexing operators in case of matrix argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of boolean array indexing - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

> In general if an index includes a Boolean array, the result will be identical to inserting `obj.nonzero()` into the same position and using the integer array indexing mechanism